# Data Compression using Trino Iceberg connector

Tags: trino, apache-iceberg

I have a situation that I am investigating, I am looking to compress parquet files that are sitting on AWS  S3, the typical sizes for those files are 90-100 MB, the reason for that is to reduce I/O operations. I am looking to use [iceberg connector](https://trino.io/docs/current/connector/iceberg.html?highlight=iceberg) to compress those files.

The problem I have is that this is experimental and I don't have a best way of going about this, are the any approaches I could adopt on using iceberg connectors?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Trino,but [spark produce][1] is a good option if you can use spark, which can help you rewrite files with a different strategy.

Examples:
```
CALL catalog_name.system.rewrite_data_files('db.sample')
```


  [1]: https://iceberg.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-procedures/

Comment: Using Iceberg just for compression is a great overkill

Comment: why? what are the other alternatives?

Comment: Are you referring to **compression** or **compaction**?

Comment: I'm referring to compression